# Transformation & Linear Regression

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this equation that I want to graph:

C(T) = γ*T + α*T^3

I realize if I factor out "T" it becomes C(T) = T(γ + α*T^2), similar to y = x(b + ax^2).

I had written most of this code for another data set and got this far but the graph I get doesn't seem right. Any suggestions?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=np.loadtxt("CvsT.txt", skiprows=1)

T=a[:,0]
C=a[:,1]

size=a.shape
rows=size[0]
xsum=0
x2sum=0
ysum=0
y2sum=0
xysum=0
for n in range(rows):
    xsum=xsum+T[n]
    x2sum=x2sum+pow(T[n],2)
    ysum=ysum+C[n]
    y2sum=y2sum+pow(C[n],2)
    xysum=xysum+T[n]*C[n]

xsum=xsum/rows
print(xsum)
x2sum=x2sum/rows
print(x2sum)
ysum=ysum/rows
print(ysum)
y2sum=y2sum/rows
print(y2sum)
xysum=xysum/rows
print(xysum)

a=(xysum-xsum*ysum)/(x2sum-xsum**2)
b=(x2sum*ysum-xsum*xysum)/(x2sum-xsum**2)
print("\nThe regression parameters are: a = ",a, "and b = ", b)

TModel=np.linspace(0.20,0.6,100)
CModel=TModel*(a*TModel+b)

plt.plot(TModel, CModel, color="red", linestyle="dashed")
plt.plot(T,C,markersize=10, color="green", marker="o", linestyle="-")
plt.xlabel("T (K)", fontweight="bold", fontsize="large")
plt.ylabel("C (mJ/mol K)", fontweight="bold", fontsize="large", 
color="green")
```

===========================================================================

```
T[K]    C[mJ/(mol K)
0.244948974 0.538887743
0.264575131 0.595294045
0.316227766 0.727323862
0.331662479 0.769456951
0.360555128 0.865332306
0.374165739 0.927931032
0.424264069 1.107329219
0.447213595 1.185116028
0.479583152 1.294874511
0.509901951 1.417527425
0.547722558 1.588395417
```

[image]

Comment: *My* suggestion is that you clarify what you mean by "doesn't seem right" :-)

Comment: In this line `CModel=TModel*(a*TModel+b)`, shouldn't `Tmodel` be squared? As: `CModel=TModel*(a*TModel**2+b)`

Comment: @Craig Yes, didn't see that

Comment: @paxdiablo I mean the red curve should be on the green one. I can't understand where I'm going wrong with my code.